# Is $\frac{0}{\pi}$ rational?

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, pi

In math lesson, our teacher showed this formula.
$Q = \{\frac{a}b\}\land (a\land b\in Q)\land (b\neq 0)$
According to this formula, $\frac{0}\pi$ is... strange.
You know, $\frac{0}\pi$ is 0 and 0 is rational. But $\pi$ is irrational. That means $b$ is irrational.
So...  Is $\frac{0}\pi$ rational?

Comment: The set of all numbers of the form $a/b$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers and $b \neq 0$ contains $0/1$, for example.

Comment: A number is rational if it has a representation of the form $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a,b$ are integers. It doesn't mean it can't have any other representations. Your number can be written as $\frac{0}{1}$, so it is rational. And by the way, please denote the set of rationals by $\mathbb{Q}$, and not $Q$.

Comment: $\frac{\pi}{\pi}$ is also rational, there is no contradiction here

Comment: Frustratingly, there are many numbers we could write that we simply don't know one way or another whether the number is rational or irrational.  For instance, $\dfrac{e}{\pi}$ we still don't know if it is rational or irrational.  Knowing whether a number is rational or not is, again, knowing whether there exists a representation of that number which is a ratio of integers or knowing that no such representation exists.  Other types of representations of the numbers are often times irrelevant.

Comment: As an aside, don't use the tag [Education] just because a question about mathematics came up during your education.  That tag is meant to be used for questions about the action of educating and the pedagogy of teaching such as "*How frequently should tests or quizzes be administered to gauge student's progress*" etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It happens that $\dfrac0\pi=\dfrac01(=0)$. So, $\dfrac0\pi$ is rational.

Also, $\dfrac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt8}$ is rational (in spite of the fact that $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt8$ are irrational), since it's equal to $\dfrac12$. It's a similar situation: the fact that I can write a number as a quotient of two numbers such that at least one of them is not an integer doesn't allow me to deduce that that number is irrational.

Comment: Thanks! This answer is helpful!